# Why do i get this error when I try installing autopep8 using pip?

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, pip, ubuntu-18.04

```
Collecting autopep8
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))    after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel   connection failed: 500 Internal Privoxy Error',))': /simple/autopep8/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 500 Internal Privoxy Error',))': /simple/autopep8/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 500 Internal Privoxy Error',))': /simple/autopep8/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 500 Internal Privoxy Error',))': /simple/autopep8/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 500 Internal Privoxy Error',))': /simple/autopep8/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement autopep8 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for autopep8
```

I tried 'pip install autopep8' then I tried 'pip3 install --upgrade autopep8' and I got the same error. It seems to be a connection issue but I am connected to the internet and can download as well as upload stuff. What is the issue with 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.'? How do I deal with this? What do I need to do to configure my proxy settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the proxy as a parameter to pip install:

```
pip install <package> --proxy http://your.proxy.net:8080/
```

If you also face ssl certificate errors (also common in corporate environments), you can enable pypi as a trusted host as well:

```
pip install <package> --proxy http://your.proxy.net:8080/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

By doing this hopefully you can solve your problem .